# How to Group the elements within group in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Employee Collection and i want to filter in such a way that first 2 columns only should be filtered and the third column values should be appended and the final result should be in a single row

The below is my code

```
List<Employe> Employeecollection = new List<Employe>();

        Employeecollection.Add(new Employe("Employee1", "Dept1","Language1"));
        Employeecollection.Add(new Employe("Employee2", "Dept2", "Language2"));
        Employeecollection.Add(new Employe("Employee3", "Dept3", "Language3"));
        Employeecollection.Add(new Employe("Employee3", "Dept3", "Language3"));
        Employeecollection.Add(new Employe("Employee1", "Dept1", "Language2"));

        foreach (Employe item in Employeecollection.GroupBy(x => new { fName = x.EmpName, lName = x.EmpDept, mName = x.KnownLanguages }).Select(g => g.First()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.EmpName + "   " + item.EmpDept + " " + item.KnownLanguages);
        }
```

but i would like to display the results like below

```
Employee1 Dept1 Language1,Language2
Employee2 Dept2 Language2
Employee3 Dept3 Language3
```

Comment: What are your current results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to group on `KnownLanguages`.  It shouldn't be included in your group selector.  The group selector should select all of thing that you want to be the same for all items in a group.

You also need to change how you print your results.  Get the common values for each of the items in a group through the `Key`, and the other values through iterating the group itself.

```
var query = Employeecollection.GroupBy(x => new
{
    x.EmpName,
    x.EmpDept
};

foreach (var group in query)
{
    string languages = string.Join(", ", 
        group.Select(employee => employee.KnownLanguages)
        .Distinct());
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key.EmpName + "   " + group.Key.EmpDept + " " 
        + languages;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Servy it is working But for Employee3 am getting Language3 2 times but i need 1 time how to solve this case?

Answer (score 5):

Group employees by name and department, then select joined string of known languages for each employee:

```
from e in Employeecollection
group e by new { e.Name, e.EmpDept } into g
select new {
   g.Key.Name,
   g.Key.EmpDept,
   Languages = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.KnownLanguages))
}
```

If you want results as single row, then do following projection instead:

```
select String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", 
    g.Key.Name, g.Key.EmpDept, String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.KnownLanguages)))
```

BTW I think its a weird property name `KnownLanguages` for property which holds single language

Comment: Thanks lazyberezovsky, But in this case we are getting Language3 as 2 times but i need to display it in one time

Comment: @yug add Distinct call `g.Select(x => x.KnownLanguages).Distinct()`